Client request fails with 502 after 2 minutes
I have website on React. From client it sends the GET request using axios to the proxy server which waits for callback from the payment engine using EventEmitter. The issue is that GET request fails after 2 minutes with 502 error.
I tried to increase the timeout using IIS 10 (Windows Server 2019) connection timeout config from 120 seconds (2 minutes) to 900 seconds (15 minutes) but it still fails after 2 minutes. I tried to set the rule to the web.config:
<serverRuntime idleTimeout="00:15:00" />
Also, I tried to set server.timeout directly to the proxy server (Node.js) but still no effect. When I enter all data very quickly in the payment form and it is submitted under 2 minutes then I get the JSON result correctly and GET request succeeds. Any ideas how to increase the timeout?

Ok. I have found the root of this issue and fixed it.
In the IIS 10 -> Application Request Routing Cache -> Server Proxy Settings -> Time-out (seconds). By default it was configured to 120 sec - 2 min. I have changed it to 900 sec - 15 min. It works well.

Now, this issue is resolved. Thanks.

First, you can try to increase request time out to solve this issue:
<system.web>
   <httpRuntime executionTimeout="180" />
</system.web>

Besides, you can also try to increase the connection timeout value to solve this issue:
Open your IIS management console , click the application and find the advanced setting, then you could modify the connection timeout value(default is 120 seconds).


I tried to set using advanced settings -> limits -> Connection Time-out but still error 502. Also, I tried to set in web.config: <httpRuntime executionTimeout="900" /> but it fails after 2 minutes. I think, it could fail bacause it sends some dummy response under 2 minutes or these executionTimeout values gets overriden somewhere in the server configs.

I think this issue is related to some internal server config or wrong proxy server concept. Thanks.
